# Proper Question for « Ces hommes parlent sans cesse. »

Tags: questions

Is the question proper for the answer?

#### Answer:

> Ces hommes parlent sans cesse.

#### Question:

> Qui parlent-ils sans cesse ?

Comment: I'm learning french as a foreign language in school. so somebody please?

Answer (score 5):

A full sentence as an answer disguises what the question was. There's no way to know which part of the sentence was asked for, except for emphasis or tone. I'll mark emphasis in **bold**.

---

#### Asking about the subject

> *Answer:* **Ces hommes** parlent sans cesse.
>
> *Question:* **Qui** parle sans cesse ?

When you're asking about the subject, or who's doing the action, you have two options: **qui** if you expect that it's a person, or **qu'est-ce qui** if you're not sure. This goes in the normal sentence order. Don't forget to make the verb agree with this question word by using the 3rd-person singular ("parle").

As Ced showed, there are other options depending on what you already know about the subject. His translates to "which people", implying that the asker knows it's a group of people that are talking.

---

#### Asking about the verb

> *Answer:* Ces hommes **parlent** sans cesse.
>
> *Question:* **Qu'est-ce que** ces hommes **font** sans cesse ?

When you're asking about the verb, or what action it is, you add *qu'est-ce que* at the beginning, where questions words tend to go, and replace the verb with *faire* in the same conjugation.

You also have the less formal option of « Ces hommes **font quoi** sans cesse ? » This is the equivalent of asking "These men are doing *what* endlessly?" — okay for conversation, a little rough for writing.

Finally, you can invert, which is more formal but you have to move things around carefully, so you might want to avoid it as a beginner. « **Que font**-ils sans cesse, ces hommes ? »

(There are even further variations possible; see Goat's comment below.)

---

#### Asking about the adverb

> *Answer:* Ces hommes parlent **sans cesse**.
>
> *Question:* **Comment est-ce que** ces hommes parlent ?

When you're asking about the adverb, or how they're doing the action, you replace *sans cesse* with *comment*, add *est-ce que*, and move it to the beginning,.

Similarly to the previous one, you can also go less formal and change the adverb in-place: « Ces hommes parlent **comment** ? »

Or you can go more formal and invert: « **Comment** ces hommes parlent-ils ? »

---

#### Asking about the object

Your example sentence doesn't include an object, so this is just for completeness.

> *Answer:* Ces hommes parlent sans cesse **de la politique**.
>
> *Question:* **De quoi est-ce que** ces hommes parlent sans cesse ?

To ask about the object, or the topic they're talking about, replace it with *qu'est-ce que* or, if it follows a preposition like *de*, replace it with *quoi*. Then move this chunk to the beginning, add *est-ce que*, and you're golden.

Similar notes on informal version: « Ces hommes parlent sans cesse de **quoi** ? »

And on inversion: « De **quoi** ces hommes parlent-ils sans cesse ? »

Comment: In the "*Asking about the verb*" section, I'd add "*Que font sans cesse ces hommes ?*" or "*Que font ces hommes sans cesse ?*"

Answer (score 2):

To the answer *« Ces hommes parlent sans cesse. »*

One of the possible questions could be:

> Quelles sont les personnes qui parlent sans cesse ?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a proper question, it's not correct.

In your question you have two pronouns, *qui* and *ils*. *parler* is **intransitive** so you can use have one.

> **Qui** parle sans cesse ? - ***Who**'s talking continuously?* (this sentence works)
>
> Parlent-**ils** sans cesse ? - *Are **they** talking continuously?* (this one doesn't, it's a yes/no question)

---

With a transitive verb if you have two pronouns, one of them acts as a complement:

> **Qui** suivent-**ils** ? - ***Who** are **they** following*?